# How to get TextField Value using Swift to make Mac App

Tags: macos, swift

I was building a Mac App using Swift. I have Email as TextField and Password as SecureField. I need to get the values of email and password which I entered after running the code.

Now I was trying as

```
@IBOutlet var Email: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet var Password: NSSecureTextField!


@IBAction func signin(sender: AnyObject) {

println("Email is: \(Email.objectValue) and password is: \(Password.objectValue)")
}
```

It returns me the output as

```
Email is: Optional(yashwanthbabu.gujarathi@gmail.com) and password is Optional(password)
```

I need to get only the values like

```
Email is: yashwanthbabu.gujarathi@gmail.com and Password is: password
```

I mean, I should not get the "Optional" in the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you do not want the `objectValue` but the `stringValue` of the fields.

```
println("Email is: \(Email.stringValue) and password is: \(Password.stringValue)")
```

Comment: If the Answer is ok for you, you can mark it as correct to let others find it more easily.

Comment: yeah sure. Forgot bout that. :) Done (y)